# want to Create post on blogger using http client I could post text content how to post content with image from my PC

Tags: http, httpclient, google-blogger-api

can anyone help with this. I want to upload images along with content to blog. Images are in my folder.

I tried the following but gets error

```
https://blogger.googleapis.com/v3/blogs/%5Bblogid%5D/posts?fetchBody=true&isDraft=true
Authorization: Bearer
application/json

{
"title": "Testing post \[blogid\]",
"content": "<p> text 1234 </p><p><img src="F:\\OWN SOFTWARE\\...\\00rk95okkk.jpg"><p>hello this is great.</p>
}
```

and get this error

```
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected , or } after key:value pair.\\n34 \\u003c/p\\u003e\\u003cp\\u003e\\u003cimg src="F:\\OWN SOFTWARE\\BAS \\n                    ^",
"errors": \[
{
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected , or } after key:value pair.\\n34 \\u003c/p\\u003e\\u003cp\\u003e\\u003cimg src="F:\\OWN SOFTWARE\\BAS \\n                    ^",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "parseError"
}
\],
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}
```

But it post to blogger if I use only

```
{
"title": "Testing post 5",
"content": "<p> text 1234 </p>
}
```